# XAML Textbox not showing the end of content while wrapping off

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have used a textbox in collision with browse button to browse some files

As i can't enable the wrapping for this textbox. I am unable to see the whole contents even when i click in the textbox and press "End" to go to the exact file name it didn't work.

I want to navigate the whole text as shown above using either arrow keys or home/end. 
Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Please can you post the XAML for your text box and button so we can see what to recommend?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably that the end part of your `TextBox` is growing behind the button. Try using a layout control as a `StackPanel` to arrange controls horizontally like below :

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
<TextBox/>
<Button/>
</StackPanel>
```

Hope it helps